# Showing documents in a folder- Power Apps

Tags: powerapps-canvas

I'm trying to get a Power Apps Gallery to show the files in a folder found on sharepoint.
The Folder name is the same as the Title column in List that is being pull in Gallery1. The Folder name is the same as the Case Name which you can see as " Case_10_j93k3na56

Here is selection of code that I'm working on:

```
Filter('Sharepoint Site', 'Folder path'= Gallery1.Selected.Title&"/")
```

[image]